# Tkinter classes: passing master to parent class

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have been successfully creating and using tkinter custom classes using this initialization format:

```
class MyWidgetFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        super().__init__()
```

But I came across a tutorial in which it was suggested that it is also necessary to pass the master (i.e. root or other container) to the parent:

```
class MyWidgetFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        super().__init__(master)
```

My custom classes have been working fine without passing master in like this. But perhaps there is something I am not understanding. Is this a suggested practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may think it’s working fine, but it’s not working the way you think it is. If you have a class that inherits from a widget, you should pass the master every time.

When you don’t pass the master, every widget will be a child of the root window. For a very simple application it might not matter much, but for even moderately complex apps it will matter.

Comment: thanks. As always, your answers are clear and to the point. In other related questions shown on this page, I've seen super().__init__(self,master) so that not only 'master' is being passed, but 'self' as well. Am I fine with just passing 'master' or does 'self' need to be there as well? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @fmex: you should not pass `self`.